# bxSlider not working on AJAX loaded content

Tags: ajax, bxslider

I am using bxSlider on my site. When I select a size from a dropdown menu, I use ajax to get specific content for my slider and input it.

The content is all there, no worries. What doesn't work is my actual slider. So when I click on the arrows, it doesn't move or anything.

On loading the new content into the slider, I call the slider function, but this doesn't work.

Any ideas?

This code below is inserting my ajax content in to the correct element on my page, then calling the slider function.

```
$('.bxslider').html(po_data.slider);
runslider();
```

Comment: Is this being called before the Ajax call can process the data

Answer (score 2):

I solved this for anyone else who is having the same problem. I destroyed the slider, then recalled it again.

```
var go_slider = null;
```

function runslider() {

```
   if (go_slider) {
      go_slider.destroySlider();
   }


   go_slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider({
      minSlides: 4,
      maxSlides: 4,
      moveSlides: 4,
      slideWidth: 208,
   });
```

}

Works perfectly! Hope this can help somebody out!